# How is this C++ expression interpreted as an invocation?

Tags: c++

In "Inside the C++ Object Model", the author gives the following example of code that is potentially ambiguous, requiring the parser to look ahead to resolve it:

> ...if C++ were to throw off the C declaration syntax, lookahead would not be required to determine that the following is an invocation of pf rather than its definition:
>
> ```
> // don’t know if declaration or invocation 
> // until see the integer constant 1024 
> int ( *pf )( 1024 );
> ```

He implies that this is interpreted as an invocation of the function `pf`. I can't see what the declaration of `pf` could be to make this a valid invocation.

Comment: Yeah, I think the author has made a mistake here.

Comment: The text is confusing. On re-reading, I think it means the line would be an invocation _in the hypothetical language without the C declaration syntax_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an ugly declaration of an `int*` called `pf` being initialized with the value 1024. However, this conversion is not valid without an explicit cast:

```
int ( *pf )((int*)1024);
```

So the line given in the question is equivalent to:

```
int* pf = 1024;
```

To understand why, consider that `int ((((*pf))));` is the same as `int* pf;`. You can put as many parentheses as you like around the declarator.

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>   `( D1 )`
>   the type of the contained *declarator-id* is the same as that of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration
>   `T D1`
>   Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded *declarator-id*, but they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

I cannot see any reason that this would be considered a function invocation. Especially considering that it begins with `int`. I can see how it could possibly be a declaration of a function pointer until it sees the integer literal. If for example, it had been this:

```
int ( *pf )(int);
```

This would be a declaration of `pf` of type pointer to function returning `int` and taking a single argument of type `int`.

Comment: The book definitely implies that it's an invocation. It's a fairly old book (it looks like it pre-dates C++98) so maybe it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

`int ( *pf )( int);` - it is declaration

Comment: That is not the same declaration.

Comment: Of course not. If this is the declaration of `pf` then `int (*pf)(1024)` is a valid expression.

Comment: @MSalters It's a redeclaration of `pf`: "error: `pf` has a previous declaration as `int (* pf)(int)`"